# Google PageSpeed third party chat loading issue

Tags: php, seo, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, livechat

I am using below code to execute live chat code through which I have added a div and chat box is showing which is working fine.

```
try {
  // LIVECHAT
  //if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 1025px)').matches)
  //{
  var __lc = {};
  __lc.license = XXXXXX;

  (function () {
     
      var lc = document.createElement("script");
      lc.type = "text/javascript";
      lc.async = true;
      lc.src =
        ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://") +
        "cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js";
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
       
  })();
  var LC_API = LC_API || {};

  LC_API.open_chat_window = function () {
    $(".chatbox").show();
    $("#chat-widget-container").show();
  };


  LC_API.on_chat_window_minimized = function () {
    
    $(".chatbox").show();
    $("#chat-widget-container").hide();
  };

  LC_API.on_chat_window_opened = function () {
    $(".chatbox").hide();
    $("#chat-widget-container").show();
  };

  LC_API.on_chat_window_hidden = function () {
    $(".chatbox").show();
    $("#chat-widget-container").show();
  };
  //}
} catch (err) {}


$(".openChat").on("click", function (event) {
  
  LC_API.open_chat_window();

  return false;
});
```

But when I go to Google Pagespeed Insights and track the website in mobile https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rosterelf.com%2F, I am getting the low rankings as its keep saying this.

> Time to Interactive 11.9 s

If I comment the above code then my percentage getting higher to above 65.

So can someone guide me how can I optimize this script to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: TTI is counting how long it takes for all your javascript libraries to load if I recall correctly.

Comment: cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js       this is third party cdn added in script if you can remove this then speed will be increased  or download it then use it then speed is also increased .

Comment: @zanderwar Its 12.7 s . Its due to chat .. as soon as I remove the chat script and its decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

When we load `javascript` on our page then under the hood many things start happening. At first, the browser downloads this file and since it's a javascript file it starts executing it and stops all other things like parsing the page further.
In your case, the same thing is happening and it is increasing the loading time for your page.
[image]

Also, you can see the `dnslookup` is taking so much time so you have improved this too. Now follow the given steps to improve your loading time.

#### Steps:

1. Preconnect to required origins. Consider adding `preconnect` or `dns-prefetch` resource hints to establish early connections to important third-party origins.
2. USe `defer` and `async` during loading your javascript files so that js execution doesn't affect page loading.
3. By preloading a certain resource, you are telling the browser that you would like to fetch it sooner than the browser would otherwise discover it because you are certain that it is important for the current page. So preload your critical js. Syntax - `<link rel="preload" as="script" href="critical.js">`

> Here you can see that you don't need a chatbox to appear at the time loading. So you can defer the javascript loading to improve page speed.

**Follow the above steps to improve your page performance affected by javascript**

#### Some more tips to increase your page speed:

1. Lazyload your images so that images download at the time when scrolls to the.
2. Preload the external font files and critical resources.
3. Use chrome dev tools coverage tab to identify the unused `CSS` and `JS`
4. Serve all your contents with  `cache-policy`. This will help you get static resources from the cache and hence improve the loading time.
5. Try using a fast CDN for serving static files.

**Most Important tip** -
From the URL I can see that your website is vulnerable to XSS attacks. So please look up into that and also work on your [security headers](https://codebulbs.com/nginx-optimization-for-best-performance-and-security/#configure-nginx-for-best-security) like `Content Security Policy (CSP)`.

For more examples see this website - https://codebulbs.com and check its source. You will get many things to learn from the source of this website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but my question is.. how should or what should I change or update in my script above ?

Comment: You can't optimize the performance by changing the above script because at last browser is going to download the script and execute it in run time. That's why I suggested you follow some practices like `preconnect` to another resource so that at the time of script downloading there is no time waste in DNS lookup and hence performance gets optimized. Check the DNS lookup time in the above image.

Comment: Also if you preload that critical js then it will get download as the browser interacts with the page.  So as a result, you will get an optimized speed index and FCP. You should get more info about core web vitals first.

Comment: This question is related to the optimization of core web vitals more.

Comment: I appreciated you because you supported me by answering my question .. that's my manners .. Coming to accepting your answer, then well I need an answer how can I update the current code .. that is an ideal answer I want to be able to achieve what I want. I already know most of the thngs you mentioned but if you can guide me to solve by updating my current code, that would be ideal dear. Thanks

Comment: I have also mentioned that you cannot optimize that script because in last the browser is going to download the `tracking.js` and no developer can eliminate execution time of javascript in a browser. You can defer the script only. Or you can trigger that script after the fully page load.

Comment: And the time i checked your website there was no best practices followed for site performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. can u explain how can I defer in my current script ? Also my SEMRush has 0 errors and around 99% scrore .. and In pagespeed for desktop it has around 95% .. i am also using lazy loading minification etc .. so can you please explain me what am I missing in terms of the best practice you are mentioning .. Thanks

Comment: to defer your script insert this `lc.defer = true;` at the place of `lc.async = true;` and your initial server response time is very very poor.

Comment: And one more thing.. pagespeed has marked some of your resources at critical resources. So I suggest you to preload them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. Yes .. intial time of responsive is poor special in mobile version hence I asked the question here in forum to get help .. Thanks for your help and suggestions. I will make the changes which you have suggested and upvote your answer if its working how I exactly wanted. I will come back soon .. Thanks

Comment: To optimize your initial server response time use caching technology like varnish in front of your web server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234011/discussion-between-lovekesh-kumar-and-mittul-at-technobrave).

Comment: I have used `lc.defer = true;` still score does not increase.

Comment: No problem.. see the above image that I have shared for your `tracking.js`. you will see that DNS lookup is taking so much time. so move your script to some fast CDN like CloudFront or Cloudflare.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used `setTimeOut` to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can optimize the script download the cdn link  `https://cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js` and save in project folder

```
lc.src =
    ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://") +
    "cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js";
```

Replace this

```
lc.src ="folder_name/tracking.js";
```

then speed of page is increased .

Comment: I tried without any success. Still the score is not improved.